# Visual Studio 2013 / Webmatrix 3 - Can not run website and The name 'WebSecurity' does not exist in the current context

Tags: visual-studio-2013, webmatrix

I've got a Website I originally wrote in Webmatrix 1 based on the Starter Site demo, but I have always used Visual Studio to edit it as you can debug from there.

The website works fine still, but I recently got a new laptop and it has the latest versions of Webmatrix and VS, and now I can not run the website locally, I get "Page can not be displayed" and also I am getting errors "The name 'WebSecurity' does not exist in the current context". If I specify the full name "WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity" then it compiles fine but will still not display the page.

I created a new Starter Site using Webmatrix 3 and it works fine (Websecurity works and website can be run and debugged locally). I have checked in _AppStart and web.config and I can not see anything obvious.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get my old website working in the new tools? Specifying the names fully is not the end of the world but I could really do with being able to run it so I can debug.

Thanks a lot,
Dave.

Answer (score 0):

I have no real clue, but your original web site was developed under an ASP.Net Webpages version that probably is not installed on your new computer.  As to the fix, if you haven't done it already, create a new site with web matrix (or visual studio...you can make asp.net web pages site with VS now I believe) and copy your code in and tweak where it bombs.  I think the differences in ASP.Net web page versions are very minimal but there might be some gotchas.  Good luck.